# Which deep learning framework have support for gtx580 GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu

I would like to train convolutional neural networks using a gtx580 gpu. I tried setting up TensorFlow but it did not work (wrong cuda compute compability).

Which deep learning framework can best support a gtx580 gpu in terms of functionality and speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use GTX 580+Tensorflow.

TensorFlow GPU support requires having a GPU card with NVidia Compute Capability >= 3.0, while GTX 580 has only 2.0 compute capability.

However, [caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe) supports CUDA compute capability 2.0. You can have a try.

### References

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#prepare_environment_for_linux

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Tensorflow with GeForce GT640 on Windows 7 x64. Also your GPU, GTX 540 is on the CUDA GPUs [list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus). So try to reinstall CUDA. It'll work!

edit: cuDNN needs GPU of compute capability 3.0 or higher.